# Matplotlib window class? OO equivalent of matplotlib.pyplot.close()?

Tags: class, matplotlib

In Matplotlib:

- I can write `matplotlib.pyplot.cla()` as `axes.clear()`, where `axes` is an `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object.
- I can write `matplotlib.pyplot.clf()` as `fig.clear()`, where `fig` is a `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object.

Then there is `matplotlib.pyplot.close()`. This closes a window. Does this window correspond to any class? Is there a `x.close()` that is equivalent to `matplotlib.pyplot.close()` but in a more object oriented style?

The source code for `matplotlib.pyplot.close()` for my version is as follows:

```
if len(args)==0:
    figManager = _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_active()
    if figManager is None: return
    else:
        _pylab_helpers.Gcf.destroy(figManager.num)
elif len(args)==1:
    arg = args[0]
    if arg=='all':
        _pylab_helpers.Gcf.destroy_all()
    elif isinstance(arg, int):
        _pylab_helpers.Gcf.destroy(arg)
    elif is_string_like(arg):
        allLabels = get_figlabels()
        if arg in allLabels:
            num = get_fignums()[allLabels.index(arg)]
            _pylab_helpers.Gcf.destroy(num)
    elif isinstance(arg, Figure):
        _pylab_helpers.Gcf.destroy_fig(arg)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Unrecognized argument type %s to close'%type(arg))
else:
    raise TypeError('close takes 0 or 1 arguments')
```

So, it appears to be based on the staticmethod
`matplotlib._pylab_helpers.Gcf.destroy` which does a variety of things I don't quite follow, noting that *In the interactive backends, this is bound to the window "destroy" and "delete" events*. But I'm not sure how figures and windows are related.

Perhaps I'm wasting my time even thinking about this.

Comment: The best advice I can offer: Don't be afraid of looking at the pyplot source code. I'll post an answer here in the next couple of days if somebody else (or you even) don't beat me too it :-) HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gcf` is a global singleton object that keeps a list of the figures you have opened with `plt.figure`.

It is essentially a dictionary with some fancy code around it to keep things consistent and  keep track of the active figure, ect.  The class that is used as a layer between `Figure` (which is what is returned by `plt.figure`) and the GUI layer is `FigureManagerBase` (and it's per-toolkit sub-classes) which is defined in `backend_bases.py`.

Which sub-class you are using is determined by which backend you are using.  These sub-classes deal with things like making sure the figure gets deleted when you click the 'x' button, and the system level gui call-backs.

`FigureManager`s have a `destroy` method which triggers their internal tear down.   In principle, if you have a `Figure` object and want to destroy it by hand, you just need to get a hold of the manager.  A reference to it isn't stored in the `Figure` object, but is stored in the `Canvas` object so you can destroy a window via

```
fig.canvas.manager.destroy()
```

which will tear the figure down, however if you do this, it might not properly clean up `Gcf`  (which will retains a reference to the figure manager) which will make future figures made with `pyplot` have unexpected numbers (it won't go back to one), `gca` will not work as exected, ect (this is the case with `Qt4`).

If you are going to use `pyplot` at all (and be sure it will always work on every backend), then you either need to

1. directly talk to `Gcf` (it's in `_pyplot_helpers.py` and really isn't too complicated once you see what it is trying to do
2. reach and talk to the GUI directly (see the code in `lib/matplotlib/tests/test_backend_qt4.py` for how to do with with `qt4`, but this is going to be very toolkit dependent)
3. `plt.close(fig.number)`

Comment: @gerrit k, removed that bit of the answer.